# MVC HTML Helper for Autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I found this example when searching for something to replace the jQuery method for autocomplete:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString AutocompleteFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string actionName, string controllerName)
 {
    string autocompleteUrl = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, 
                                                   actionName,
                                                   controllerName,
                                                   null,
                                                   html.RouteCollection,
                                                   html.ViewContext.RequestContext,
                                                   includeImplicitMvcValues: true);
    return html.TextBoxFor(expression, 
                          new 
                            { 
                              data_autocomplete_url = autocompleteUrl 
                            });
 }
```

But it doesn't like the "Expression" in the argument.  What am I doing wrong with this?

Comment: Have you included `using System.Linq.Expressions;`?

Comment: "it doesn't like" ... could you tell us what error you get?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - yes, that was the problem, had to include that namespace.  Ooops!